# How to load external dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

How can I load external dataset instead of mnist?

```
# underscore to omit the label arrays
(train_images, train_labels), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data() 


train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]

BUFFER_SIZE = 60000
BATCH_SIZE = 256

# Batch and shuffle the data
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

I've tried flow_from_directory "(train_images, _) = train_generator" but can not extract image values as the above code

```
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                            rescale=1./255)
                                            #rotation_range=10,  
                                            #zoom_range = 0.10,  
                                            #width_shift_range=0.1, 
                                            #height_shift_range=0.1 


train_generator = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                                    batch_size=256,
                                                    color_mode="grayscale",
                                                    directory='../input/main-dataset110/Train',
                                                    shuffle=True, 
                                                    target_size=(28, 28), 
                                                    class_mode='sparse')

(train_images, _) = train_generator
```

Comment: "*but can not extract image values*" - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found a code which helped

```
try:

    import tensorflow as tf
    import cv2
    import os
    import pickle
    import numpy as np
    print("Library Loaded Successfully ..........")
except:
    print("Library not Found ! ")


class MasterImage(object):

    def __init__(self,PATH='', IMAGE_SIZE = 28):
        self.PATH = PATH
        self.IMAGE_SIZE = IMAGE_SIZE

        self.image_data = []
        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []
        self.CATEGORIES = []

        # This will get List of categories
        self.list_categories = []

    def get_categories(self):
        for path in os.listdir(self.PATH):
            if '.DS_Store' in path:
                pass
            else:
                self.list_categories.append(path)
        print("Found Categories ",self.list_categories,'\n')
        return self.list_categories

    def Process_Image(self):
        try:
            """
            Return Numpy array of image
            :return: X_Data, Y_Data
            """
            self.CATEGORIES = self.get_categories()
            for categories in self.CATEGORIES:                                                  # Iterate over categories

                train_folder_path = os.path.join(self.PATH, categories)                         # Folder Path
                class_index = self.CATEGORIES.index(categories)                                 # this will get index for classification

                for img in os.listdir(train_folder_path):                                       # This will iterate in the Folder
                    new_path = os.path.join(train_folder_path, img)                             # image Path

                    try:        # if any image is corrupted
                        image_data_temp = cv2.imread(new_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)                 # Read Image as numbers
                        image_temp_resize = cv2.resize(image_data_temp,(self.IMAGE_SIZE,self.IMAGE_SIZE))
                        self.image_data.append([image_temp_resize,class_index])
                    except:
                        pass

            data = np.asanyarray(self.image_data)

            # Iterate over the Data
            for x in data:
                self.x_data.append(x[0])        # Get the X_Data
                self.y_data.append(x[1])        # get the label

            X_Data = np.asarray(self.x_data) / (255.0)      # Normalize Data
            Y_Data = np.asarray(self.y_data)

            # reshape x_Data

            X_Data = X_Data.reshape(-1, self.IMAGE_SIZE, self.IMAGE_SIZE, 1)

            return X_Data, Y_Data
        except:
            print("Failed to run Function Process Image ")

    def pickle_image(self):

        """
        :return: None Creates a Pickle Object of DataSet
        """
        # Call the Function and Get the Data
        X_Data,Y_Data = self.Process_Image()

        # Write the Entire Data into a Pickle File
        pickle_out = open('X_Data','wb')
        pickle.dump(X_Data, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

        # Write the Y Label Data
        pickle_out = open('Y_Data', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(Y_Data, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

        print("Pickled Image Successfully ")
        return X_Data,Y_Data

    def load_dataset(self):

        try:
            # Read the Data from Pickle Object
            X_Temp = open('X_Data','rb')
            X_Data = pickle.load(X_Temp)

            Y_Temp = open('Y_Data','rb')
            Y_Data = pickle.load(Y_Temp)

            print('Reading Dataset from PIckle Object')

            return X_Data,Y_Data

        except:
            print('Could not Found Pickle File ')
            print('Loading File and Dataset  ..........')

            X_Data,Y_Data = self.pickle_image()
            return X_Data,Y_Data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '../input/main-dataset110/Test'
    a = MasterImage(PATH=path,
                    IMAGE_SIZE=28)

    X_Data,Y_Data = a.load_dataset()
    print(X_Data.shape)
```